# Dynamic Select Options to Show and Hide Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I've created dynamic select fields that change options based on "product" selection.**

The value's of the options get combined into a string which gets scanned in a series of **if statements** in order to show particular div's.

```
if(this.value == "1"){
      // REMOVES PREVIOUS SUC CLASS ON LOAD
      $(".suc").remove();
      // APPENDS TO DOWNLOAD
      $(".download").append("<option class='suc' value='1' > 30ghz to 40ghz </option>");
      $(".download").append("<option class='suc' value='2' > 50ghz to 70ghz </option>");
      $(".download").append("<option class='suc' value='3' > 80ghz to 100ghz </option>");
      //APPENDS TO UPLOAD
      $(".upload").append("<option class='suc' value = '1' > 1ghz to 5ghz </option>");
      $(".upload").append("<option class='suc' value = '2' > 5ghz to 10ghz </option>");
      $(".upload").append("<option class='suc' value = '3' > 10ghz to 50ghz </option>");

      // REMOVES OPTION VALUE FROM SELECT
      $(".doorbell").remove();
      $(".chime").remove();

    }
```

For example , it would create the string '123' and that would show whatever div I want to show according to my if / else statement below.

```
var $selects = $('.question select');
$selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
// puts values into array
function getValues() {
  var vals = $selects.map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  if (vals.join('') === "111") {
    $('.selection-1').fadeIn('swing');
  } else { $('.selection-1').hide();}
```

**The issue is, when I have 2 different options that should show the same div - the div does not show.**

( I found a small solution but then I'm using a series of 'if' statements back to back and I'm not sure if that is good practice )

```
  if (vals.join('') === "111") {
    $('.selection-1').fadeIn('swing');
  } else { $('.selection-1').hide();}
  // When another value is selected in the same select field it's completely hidden
    if (vals.join('') === "121") {
    $('.selection-1').fadeIn('swing');
  } else { $('.selection-1').hide();}
```

**For example if the values added up to '111' or '121' or '131' and they all needed to unhide .selection-1 it would not be able to unhide, I showed the example in the jsfiddle.**

**I've attempted to fit everything into a switch statement**, but I couldn't quite figure out how and I've been cranking this out for a few days :(.

I'll include my jsfiddle so you can see this semi live, thank you in advance and I'm open to any other solutions !

https://jsfiddle.net/Micah_C/uwqtt05a/

Comment: I don't get it! In your code you are listening on a change event for the products id, which values are 1,2 and 3, but your if condition is looking for value 4 and 7!

Comment: Hey @jmmontero I don't think my if condition is looking for the value 4 and 7 :o – it first creates an array with the values that are selected for example: ['1','1','1'] and then it joins to create '111' so within the first product it can only range from 1-3 and it will always be in the 3 string format ? I think. I nipped from a few other questions on here but still no luck :/

Comment: Review the code again! It is doing it! Every time you select an option on the products go to this line `$('#products').on('change', function() {`